# Why am I getting "The directive 'control' is unknown" error in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on an editor page for a project in ASP.NET MVC. I would like to use a control for both the create page and the edit page so I don't have to duplicate code. I've set up an `EditorTemplates` folder inside `/Views/Shared` to hold my templates. And I've placed a .ascx file in there called `ArticlePresentation.ascx`.

`ArticlePresentation.ascx` looks like this:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<genesis.Core.Presentation.ArticlePresentation>" %>

Testing the control
```

My `Edit.aspx` view looks like this:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/genesis.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<genesis.Core.Presentation.ArticlePresentation>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Edit
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

    <h2>Edit</h2>
    <% using (Html.BeginForm()) {%>
        <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(ArticlePresentation => ArticlePresentation)%>
    <% } %>

    <div>
        <%: Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index") %>
    </div>

</asp:Content>
```

I can build the site without getting any errors, but, when I run the site and browse to the editing page I get this error:

> System.Web.HttpParseException was unhandled by user code
>
> ```
>  Message=The directive 'control' is unknown.
>
>  Source=System.Web
>
>  ErrorCode=-2147467259
>
>  WebEventCode=0
>
>  FileName=C:<path to folder>asp.net mvc\genesis\genesis\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ArticlePresentation.aspx
>
>  Line=2
>
>  VirtualPath=/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/ArticlePresentation.aspx
>
>  StackTrace:
>
>       at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding)
>
>       at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath)
>
>       at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseInternal()
>
>       at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse()
>
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType()
>
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider)
>
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders()
>
>       at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild()
> ```
>
> etc... etc...etc...

I've searched google looking for solutions, but everything I've found so far relates to having the control in an aspx page rather than a ascx page.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because your file has an `.aspx` extension and not `.ascx`. Read the error message carefully:

> ErrorCode=-2147467259
>
> WebEventCode=0
>
> FileName=C:\Documents and
>   Settings\bquakkelaar\Desktop\dropstuff\asp.net
>   mvc\genesis\genesis\Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\ArticlePresentation.**aspx**

Now rename the file to `ArticlePresentation.ascx` and everything will work as expected.

Also you could replace this line:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(ArticlePresentation => ArticlePresentation)%>
```

with this:

```
<%: Html.EditorForModel() %>
```

Comment: Hey Darin - thanks a lot for the help and tips. I've noticed you've helped me out before with some great advice. I am very confused with this one becaue when I use the solution explorer to browse to the \Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\, the only file in there is called ArticlePresentation.ascx. I don't understand why the error says says that it's an aspx

Comment: Is there a way to jolt VWD 2010 Express into re-assesing the files in that folder?

Comment: Thanks for that attention to detail Darin. Apparently, I had 2 files in there (an aspx and an ascx) but the solution explorer was only displaying the ascx. I deleted the aspx using windows explorer and built the project again. viola! it werkd. Thanks